# Why is BigQuery Sandbox saying its ERROR: Expected keyword AS but got "(" at [1:17]

Tags: temp-tables, with-clause

Is this an issue with BigQuerry. I was follwing along with [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qfyynHBFOsM) youtube video and for some reason this code will not work.

```sql
    WITH pop_vs_vac (continent, location, DATE, population, new_vaccinations, rolling_people_vaccinated)
AS (
    SELECT dea.continent, dea.location, dea.DATE, dea.population, vac.new_vaccinations, SUM(CASt(vac.new_vaccinations AS INT)) OVER (
            PARTITION BY dea.location ORDER BY dea.location, dea.DATE
            ) AS rolling_peoploe_vaccinated --(rollling_people_vaccinated/population)* 100
    FROM [gg-analytics-404715.Portfolio_Covid.Covid_Deaths] AS dea
    JOIN [gg-analytics-404715.Portfolio_Covid.Covid_vaccinations] AS vac
        ON dea.location = vac.location
            AND dea.DATE = vac.DATE
    WHERE dea.continent IS NOT NULL
        --- order by 1, 2, 3
    )
SELECT *
FROM pop_vs_vac
```

Comment: Not sure but your column specified in the column list (rolling_people_vaccinated) does not match what you put in the inner query (rolling_peoploe_vaccinated).  Additionally, I don't think big query lets you rename the column inside like that.

Comment: It might also be helpful to share the "some reasons" why this is not working, i.e. error messages and the like.